# SQL query, can't print datetime?

Tags: php, sql

I can't print this sql select query. I can't see the error, all the link connection are good

```
<?php
    $strsql33  = "SELECT `time` FROM tssa_banner_central WHERE where co=$codigo";
    $weews = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'teatrotrail', 'pass','teatrotrail');

    $resultt=mysqli_query($weews,$strsql33);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt)) {
        if($row["time"] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
        } else{;
            echo($row["time"]);
        }
    };
?>
```

Comment: Where is the use of prepared statements?
Anyway,  you've forgot an apostrophe before the $codigo.

Should the $codigo be a string or integer?

Comment: probably should not have $codingo in there. Use prepared statements

Comment: edited no more stmts

Comment: You changed the code entirely. Please use prepared statements and follow the [official documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-row-examples). Also, your last edit didn't fix the sql statement; have a good look at the quotes.

Comment: you (also) have 2x `WHERE`'s here.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the single quote after "$codigo" and you'll probably be good.